# Dart packages, i dont know what to do

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

How do i do with this command:

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:
dependencies:
node_preamble: ^2.0.0

I don't understand, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Open the `pubspec.yaml` file located inside the root folder of your project
and you can add the package like this, inside the dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  node_preamble: ^2.0.0
```

Or click [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages) to see the documentation from flutter.dev

Comment: I try to run this command: pub get packages, but the result :Could not find a file name "pubspec.yaml

Comment: Were you in the same directory as the pubspec.yaml?  And it's just "flutter pub get" or "dart pub get"... no word "packages" there.